# who will decide the data type size in embedded C programming

Tags: c, embedded

Who will decide the Data type size in Embedded C programming wheather it is compiler or Microcontroller

Comment: Let us suppose if I am using 16/32 bit microcontroller and if i declare Int variable who will decide wheather Integer is 2 byte or 4 byte

Answer (score 6):

The microcontroller is passive, it's a piece of hardware. C is typically a compiled language, the compiler generates machine code that's ready to run on the target. There is little space for someone else to decide, so it's up to the compiler.

But it's *very much* up to the compiler, it's perfectly possible to design a compiler with "bad" choices, i.e. a compiler for an 8-bit micro that uses 64-bit `int`s everywhere. It would result in very bad performance for the code, but that's "just" performance.

Comment: So compiler it self taking care if i m declaring a int variable and assign 4 bytes if the compiler is 32-bit?

Comment: Use `sizeof` to know how many bytes each data type consumes.  For example, `sizeof int`.

Comment: @user3083191 Yes, the implementor(s) of the compiler make(s) those choices.